# Web Crawling/Scraping - Build or Buy?

Tags: web-crawler, web-scraping

It seems to me that at this point in time, one single tool would have ascended to dominance, because the process seems generic enough: point to a starting URL, interact with its forms and scripts, follow the links, download the data. Rinse, repeat. While I’ve always derived a certain sense of satisfaction at building ad hoc apps to jump through the hoops to get a few hundred gig of documents on my hard drive, I wonder if I’m not just recreating the wheel.

I confess I haven’t tried some commercial products like Automation Anywhere, but since I’m trying to make a go full time doing what I really like doing, analyzing the data rather than retrieving it, I’m hoping the wisdom of the crowd here can point me in the direction of a definitive discussion.  Is it just that there are too many quirks to have a single-tool-fits-almost-all situations?

And let me clarify or complicate this – I have looked at a number of browser “macro”-type tools, like iRobot, iOpus and found them to be slow.  For seriously large document collections, I’d want to run crawlers on a cluster/cloud and so I’m just not sure how these would work in that environment.  For my use case, let’s say I want to

- retrieve roughly a million documents
- from a site that doesn’t require log in but makes heavy use of javascript for navigation.
- Use Amazon or Azure servers to do the work.

An example might be this site, from the US Census (there are more efficient ways to get data from them, but the style of the site is a good example of data volume and navigation):

http://factfinder2.census.gov/faces/nav/jsf/pages/searchresults.xhtml?ref=addr&refresh=t

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it tends to be a somewhat gray area in the software world, such tools seem to be slow to emerge.

There is significant work being done in similar fields like automated site testing via headless browsers (like iRobot and iOpus that you mentioned). I see Selenium mentioned a lot too, and there are some interesting tools using Apple Webkit like [phantomjs](http://www.phantomjs.org/), but I can't comment on their speed or "cloud-ability".

An interesting option that has been gaining significant traction lately could be the [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) javascript runtime. The last I checked (6 months ago) there were some projects poking at using node for scraping, implementing a highly light-weight javascript-interpreting browser.  ...And I believe there are node options for the cloud already.

However, AFAIK, the fastest scrapers are still those that don't interpret javascript, and rely on the old-fashioned pre-decomposition of the http requests by the developer.

Answer (score 2):

[Apache Nutch](http://nutch.apache.org/) is a very powerful crawler:

- It's highly scalable.
- It has the ability to crawl a specific website only (ignoring external links).
- One of the fastest open-source crawlers at the moment.
- Built from the ground up [with big data in mind (i.e. integrates with Hadoop and allows you to run MapReduce jobs on the data)](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/FAQ#MapReduce).
- Has various plugins, [including a JavaScript parser.](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/Features)

Of course, it's written in Java, but if you're familiar with C# then Java shouldn't be that foreign. Some people have expressed concerns about the complexity of Nutch, but for anybody that's doing serious crawling it's going to be much easier to learn the caveats of Nutch than to build a similar web crawler.